# How to extract a RSA private key from an ssh-agent core dump

Tags: rsa, forensics, memory, reverse-engineering, openssh

I need to extract an RSA private key from an ssh-agent core dump running on ubuntu 20.04. I believe the ssh version is the latest. I have tried many Linux tools with no luck. I also wrote a python program to return the section of the core dump with the highest entropy (inconclusive).
I have access to the ssh-agent binary and the core dump file.

```
$ file core
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'ssh-agent', real uid: 0, effective uid: 0, real gid: 0, effective gid: 101, execfn: '/usr/bin/ssh-agent', platform: 'x86_64'
```

```
$ file ssh-agent
ssh-agent: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=3734cf9330cd22aab10a4b215b8bcf789f0c6aeb, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

The version of openssl being used is OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Just checking: are you sure the key itself is in the dump, rather than just e.g. a file descriptor open to the key file and the passphrase / derived unwrapping key actually resident in memory? If past versions had the entire key in memory you're probably good, but there's no inherent reason it needs to be.

Comment: I know the key is in memory I don't know if it is encrypted or not. If so I can crack it after I find a way to extract it.

Comment: I already tried basic methods like searching for the armored parts I think it is encoded in binary form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an automating tool to do this.
Repo: [here](https://github.com/Kracken256/ssh-keyfinder)

Usage: python3 ./ssh-keyfinder.py

It will extract all private keys from core dump. Supports RSA and ECDSA (ed25519).